# send data from java to javascript page into a href function

Tags: javascript, java, href, struts

I want to send variable into onclick function, but I did not succeed to get the suitable code.
this is the java code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < projetList.size(); i++) { 
    contenuTableHTML.append("<tr>");
    contenuTableHTML.append("<td class='width1'><div class='coupe'>" + projetList.get(i).getProjectAbr() + "</div></td>");
    contenuTableHTML.append("<td class='width3'><div class='coupe'>" + projetList.get(i).getProjectTkt() + "</div></td>");
    List<String> objList = projetList.get(i).getObjectList();
    contenuTableHTML.append("<div id='objList' name='objList' value='objList'>");
    contenuTableHTML.append("<td class='width3'><div class='coupe'> <a href='#' **onclick='popupFunction(objList)**'>" + projetList.get(i).getObjectList().size() + "</div></td>");            
    contenuTableHTML.append("</div>");
    contenuTableHTML.append("<td class='tableTicketsSummaryTd width3'><div class='coupe'>" + projetList.get(i).getProjectDomain() + "</div></td>");
    contenuTableHTML.append("</tr>");
}
```

As below the javascript code:

```
function popupFunction(obj) {
    objList = document.getElementById(obj);
    console.log("objList ",objList);
    console.log("obj: ", obj);

    var w = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=300");
    w.document.write(obj);
    w.document.close();
    w.focus();
}
```

I always get objList and obj as null.

Comment: You need to read about ```AJAX```

Comment: @Antaaaa Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` template in html, should be dynamic to send an actual argument (`objList`) to the `javascript` function.

You can make use of `template literals` or `dynamic strings` while creating your HTML in the following way by adding  `(`template literal`) and accessing dynamic elements using ${element} inside the` template literal``:

```
 contenuTableHTML.append(`<div id=${objList} name=${objList} value=$[objList}>`);
 contenuTableHTML.append(`<td class='width3'><div class='coupe'> <a href='#' onclick='popupFunction(${objList})'>` + projetList.get(i).getObjectList().size() + "</div></td>");
```

This will allow you to access `objList` and `obj` in your javascript function.